# Scripts in ngOnInit after HTTP subscribe fail to activate

Tags: angular, http, observable

I'm learning Angular and I can't seem to find a solution to this problem. I am subscribing to an HTTP service. However after subscribing, all scripts after do not activate. Even a simple console.log of the data won't activate.

It works if I do this:

```
    this._colorsService.returnColorsHttp()
      .subscribe(
        (data: any) => {
          this.colors = data;
          this.totalColors = data.length;
          this.colorRows = Array.from(Array(Math.ceil(this.totalColors / this.colorItemsPerRow)).keys())
          console.log(this.totalColors);
          console.log(this.colorRows);
        }
      );
  }
```

However, it fails if I do this:

```
    this._colorsService.returnColorsHttp()
      .subscribe(
        (data: any) => {
          this.colors = data;
          this.totalColors = data.length;
        }
      );
    this.colorRows = Array.from(Array(Math.ceil(this.totalColors / this.colorItemsPerRow)).keys())
    console.log(this.totalColors);
    console.log(this.colorRows);
  }
```

Thank you in advance!

Comment: The first way is the correct method to access asynchronous data. In the second way `this.totalColors` might be undefined when accessed outside the subscription.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Code inside subscription gets invoked when response from service is received successfully, till then it doesn't gets blocked and proceed further to code below subscription. As soon as response is received, After that only it executes code inside subscription block.

Thats how asynchronous tasks work.

Comment: does that mean it proceeds to run the next script even before getting a response? That is why console.log(this.totalColors); and console.log(this.colorRows); return undefined?

Answer (score 0):

The following should be placed inside your subscription:

```
this.colorRows = Array.from(Array(Math.ceil(this.totalColors / 
this.colorItemsPerRow)).keys())
console.log(this.totalColors);
console.log(this.colorRows);
```

Like this:

```
this._colorsService.returnColorsHttp()
  .subscribe((data: any) => {
      this.colors = data;
      this.totalColors = data.length;

      this.colorRows = Array.from(Array(Math.ceil(this.totalColors / 
      this.colorItemsPerRow)).keys())
      console.log(this.totalColors);
      console.log(this.colorRows);
    }
  );
```

}